# Getting rid of if/else while calling similar classes Java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the problem that I want to and need to get rid of some if else cases. I got the following code in my project:

```
if (ar[4].equals("week")) {

    WeekThreshold wt = new WeekThreshold();
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(wt.getStartDate().getTime());
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(wt.getEndDate().getTime());

} else if (ar[4].equals("month")) {

    MonthThreshold mt = new MonthThreshold();
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(mt.getStartDate().getTime());
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(mt.getEndDate().getTime());

} else if (ar[4].equals("quarter")) {

    quarterThreshold();

} else if (ar[4].equals("year")) {

    YearThreshold yt = new YearThreshold();
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(yt.getStartDate().getTime());
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(yt.getEndDate().getTime());
}
```

That three classes `WeekThreshold`, `MonthThreshold` and `YearThreshold` extend from an `AbstractThreshold` class where they get dates from a calendar, but that is not important. The method `quarterThreshold()` is special and can stay there. But how can I get rid of that if else blocks and have one statement to call different classes?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the classes that need to be called are from a variety of the array `ar[]`. If the array `ar[4]` is month, `MonthThreshold` must be called, etc.

Comment: Have you considered the Factory design pattern?

Comment: Thats what I was told by a mate, too, but I'm pretty fresh to oop...I'll google it, but of course any tips would be nice, too :)

Comment: I will code something for you ... gimme a minute

Comment: If you want to get rid of _imperative_ code (`if` / `else`), you need a _declarative_ solution; use an `enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can make good use of the FactoryPattern

```
class ThresholdFactory
{
  public static AbstractThreshold getThreshold(String criteria)
  {
    if ( criteria.equals("week") )
      return new WeekThreshold();
    if ( criteria.equals("month") )
      return new MonthThreshold();
    if ( criteria.equals("year") )
      return new YearThreshold();

    return null;
  }
}
```

The rest of the code looks then like this:

```
AbstractThreshold at = ThresholdFactory.getThreshold(ar[4]);
if(at != null){
  firstTime = unparsedDate.format(at.getStartDate().getTime());
  secondTime = unparsedDate.format(at.getEndDate().getTime());
} else {
   quarterThreshold();
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks! Nice code to understand how the Factory works :)

Comment: @wg15music, note that you still have the same amount of if-else statements you wanted to get rid of. They just moved to the separate method.

Comment: But I was told I could use the Factory Pattern...I could probably add some enums or Hashmap...but in the end I am not able to get completely rid of those, am I right? They have to be somewhere...I'll show it to my supervisor and hope it is enough for him :)

Comment: You can eliminate the `if`s by using an `enum`.

Comment: or using a Map, i know. But its debatable if its worth the boilerplate to get rid of 3 if statements -.-
I will refrain my statement.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple possibilities... Do the XYZThreshold classes have a common interface, like Threshold? Then you could assign a variable with that, for example...

```
Threshold threshold = null;
if ((ar[4].equals("week")) {
  threshold = new WeekThreshold();
} else ... {

}

firstTime = unparsedDate.format(threshold.getStartDate().getTime());
secondTime = unparsedDate.format(threshold.getEndDate().getTime());
```

That would be a first step. If you wanted, you could, for example, use an enum to store your Thresholds:

```
enum Thresholds {
  WEEK("week") {

     public Threshold getThreshold() {
           return new WeekThreshold();
     }
  },
  etc.

  private String period;

  private Thresholds(String period) {
    this.period = period;
  }

  public abstract Threshold getThreshold();

  //  ...add a static class to iterate and search by period, 
  // ...so you can write Threshold threshold = Thresholds.getByPeriod("week").getThreshold();
}
```

Using enums is a personal taste, of course, you can do the same thing with normal classes or by simply putting your if-block for the Threshold-choosing into a seperate class.

Comment: They all use the same AbstractClass, yes

Comment: The difference depends on the question if you want a new instance every time or not. If not, you can construct the enum with one instance, true. Otherwise you need the other version - or reflection.

Comment: OP's problem seem like a perfect fit for a rich `enum` as you have sketched here. Much more elegant than a plain `String` / `Map` based solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can merge the common code (`unparsedDate.format(...)`) outside like this:

```
AbstractThreshold at = null;
switch(ar[4]) {
case "week":
    at = new WeekThreshold();
    break;
case "month":
    at = new MonthThreshold();
    break;
case "year":
    at = new YearThreshold();
    break;
case "quarter":
    quarterThreshold();
    break;
}
if(at != null) {
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(at.getStartDate().getTime());
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(at.getEndDate().getTime());
}
```

Of course an overengineered version is possible. Here's just an illustration how it can be implemented using the Java-8 features:

```
// Map can be initialized only once, then used many times
Map<String, Supplier<AbstractThreshold>> thresholdSuppliers = new HashMap<>();
thresholdSuppliers.put("week", WeekThreshold::new);
thresholdSuppliers.put("month", MonthThreshold::new);
thresholdSuppliers.put("year", YearThreshold::new);

AbstractThreshold at = thresholdSuppliers.getOrDefault(ar[4], () -> null).get();
if(at != null) {
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(at.getStartDate().getTime());
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(at.getEndDate().getTime());
} else if(ar[4].equals("quarter"))
    quarterThreshold();
}
```

Comment: sadly not allowed to use switch/case as it is too similar to if/else

Comment: @wg15music, not allowed by who?

Comment: supervisor, as that are practises to get deeper into OOP

Comment: @wg15music, added a new version just to confuse your supervisor :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to use interfaces and Factory design pattern
If your multiple implementors share common code, have them all extend an Abstract class that implements the interface. It is a good idea to refer to your methods through the interface, not the concrete class to take advantage of polymorphism ... see code below ...

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] intervals = {"week", "week", "quarter", "month", "year", "week"}; 

        IThreshold[] objects = new IThreshold[intervals.length];

        // Create your objects using Factory pattern
        for(int index = 0; index < intervals.length; index++) {
            objects[index] = ThresholdFactory.createInstance(intervals[index]);
        }

        // Now iterate through your objects and refer to them through a common interface
        for(IThreshold object : objects) {
            int start = object.getFirstTime();
            int end = object.getFirstTime();
        }
    }
}

interface IThreshold {
    public int getFirstTime();
    public int getLastTime();
}


abstract class AbstractThreshold implements IThreshold {

    @Override
    public int getFirstTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLastTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}

class WeekThreshold extends AbstractThreshold {}
class MonthThreshold extends AbstractThreshold {}
class QuarterThreshold extends AbstractThreshold {}
class YearThreshold extends AbstractThreshold {}

class ThresholdFactory {

    public static final IThreshold createInstance(String interval) {
        IThreshold instance = null;

        if(interval.equals("week")){
            instance = new WeekThreshold();
        } 
        else if(interval.equals("month")){
            instance = new MonthThreshold();
        } 
        else if(interval.equals("quarter")){
            instance = new QuarterThreshold();
        } 
        else {
            if(interval.equals("year")){
                instance = new YearThreshold();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first create threshold factory,

```
static enum ThresholdsFactory {


        week(new WeekThreshold()), month(new MonthThreshold())/* etc */;

        static private Map<String,ThresholdsFactory> lookup = new HashMap<String, ThresholdsFactory>();
        static{
            for(ThresholdsFactory val :  ThresholdsFactory.values()){
            lookup.put(val.name(), val);
            }
        }

        public AbstractThreshold threshold;

        public static ThresholdsFactory find(String name){
            return lookup.get(name);
        }

        ThresholdsFactory(AbstractThreshold th) {
            threshold = th;
```

}
    }

now all what you need to do is

```
AbstractThreshold th = ThresholdsFactory.find(ar[4]);

if (th!=null){
    firstTime = unparsedDate.format(th.getStartDate().getTime());
    secondTime = unparsedDate.format(th.getEndDate().getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement

```
String typeOfDay;
     switch (dayOfWeekArg) {
         case "Monday":
             typeOfDay = "Start of work week";
             break;
         case "Tuesday":
         case "Wednesday":
         case "Thursday":
             typeOfDay = "Midweek";
             break;
         case "Friday":
             typeOfDay = "End of work week";
             break;
         case "Saturday":
         case "Sunday":
             typeOfDay = "Weekend";
             break;
         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
     }
```

You can replace the example that I stole from java documentation, with your own code

```
switch(periodType){
    case "week":
      WeekThreshold wt = new WeekThreshold();
    break; // add your other cases
}
firstTime = unparsedDate.format(wt.getStartDate().getTime());
secondTime = unparsedDate.format(wt.getEndDate().getTime());
```

Comment: String-Switches only work for Java 7+, but that shouldn't normally be a problem, just wanted to mention it.